# Java i need to get the region of image that contains the hand and then scale/resize this to fixed dimensions for my neural network

Tags: java, image, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, image-recognition

Converted an image to HSB format to recognize skin for a hand gesture recognition, but struggling on how to get the x and y coordinates of the hand only, so that I can remove the unneeded pixels so I can put it into a neural network.

Currently, I am using a for loop to go through the original image, collecting the RGB values and converting them to HSB.

[This is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtTrb.png)

I think if I can turn the hand to white pixels instead of displaying the hand, I should because able to set a loop to look for the white pixels and only pick them out

Comment: I don’t understand what you want your code to produce.  You say you want “the x and y coordinates”;  does that mean you want a list of Point objects for every pixel of the hand?  A list of Points representing an outline of the hand?

Comment: Well, my aim is to create an image recognition program but first, I aim to be able to put this image into a neural network, I can't exactly put the image by itself into the network as it won't take images that big so I wish to make a new image which only has the pixels from the hand only which is why I assumed getting the x and y coordinates may be helpful. Though if you think a list of points can help accomplish this goal that would be helpfull.

Comment: x and y coordinates of what?  Are you trying to get a single x value and a single y value? What would be those x and y values for your example image?

Comment: I would expect it to be multi-able x and y's since I would be able to use a for loop to go through the image and find the first coordinate of the white hand from both width and height so i would be able to pull out just what i need expecting something like this https://gyazo.com/f2a40a32b8d3bb0f7ba9bb383c233ff1 (Sorry if i am hard to understand learning about java )

Comment: would a better statement of the problem be: i'm given an image that should contain a hand. i need to get the region of image that contains the hand and then scale/resize this to fixed dimensions so i can provide a uniform sized tensor for my neural network. Seems to me like you just need a 2 layer approach. 1 NN to detect hands and draw bounding box 1.1 capture that region and manipulate to pass to second NN

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I would need, again apologies for my bad explanation do you know any good tutorials on how I can go about doing that? I am currently using neuroph.